# How to distract a file from a discord channel and send it to another discord channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I already have to following:

```js
if (message.channel.id === 'CHANNEL ID 1') {
  if (message.attachments.size >= 1 ) {
    client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID 2').send(`${message.author}: TEST SUCCESFULL`);
  }
}
```

But now instead of `"TEST SUCCESFULL"` I want the file, so it sends the file to another channel. AND if possible, I want to make that if you send a file in CHANNEL 1, the file gets deleted in channel 1 (and send to channel 2)

I hope u guys can help me and understand the question!
Kind Regards.

Comment: So what do you use, discord.js or java? JS and Java are completely different languages...

Comment: Im so sorry, I ment Discord.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly understood! From what I understand, the process would be to:

1. Check if the file has attachments (and you already do that).
2. Send the file to the other channel.
3. Delete the file from the original channel.

This, however, will not work for files with sizes over 8 MB, since bots are limited to 8 MB files only (unlike Nitro users who can upload up to 100 MB). So you have two choices here: **(A)** Either grab the link from the message (however you won't be able to delete that message), or **(B)** handle messages over 8 MB (either by ignoring them or deleting them only, without reuploading).

Both solutions I provide will also work with images and videos. If you don't want that, just check if the attachment has a width (`attachments[0].width == null` for example). If there is a width, the file is an image or video. Otherwise, it's a file.

### Option A

You'll first have to pull the link from the message, and then post that link in the new channel. This is pretty straightforward.

```js
// The incoming message is `message`.
if (message.channel.id === 'CHANNEL ID 1') {
  // No need for a size check since this will be run 0 times if
  // there are no attachments.
  message.attachments.each(attachment => {
    client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID 2').send(attachment.url);
  });
}
```

However in this case, you are not allowed to delete the message, or else the file will be removed from Discord's servers as well.

### Option B

This will send the attachments of the original message onto the other channel.

```js
// The incoming message is `message`.
if (message.channel.id === 'CHANNEL ID 1') {
  if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
    // Size check (8000000 bytes is 8 MB)
    if (attachment.size > 8000000) { /* Pick an option below. */ }

    client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID 2')
      .send({
        "files": message.attachments.map(attachment => attachment.url)
      });
  }
}
```

In such case, `message.attachments.map(...)` is an array of URLs containing the sent attachments. These will be downloaded and sent back to Discord. What happens if the file passes 8 MB is up to you, but both end with never sending the message at all.

#### Option B.1

You can choose not to relay the message, and instead do absolutely nothing. The original message is kept, and nothing is sent to the other channel.

```js
if (attachment.size > 8000000) { return; /* Ends the entire function. */ }
```

In case you plan to do something else after this part of your code, you can simply negate the expression (which would be `attachment.size < 8000000`) and wrap the sending statement (`client.channels.cache...`) inside of that if statement.

#### Option B.2

You can choose to delete the message without relaying it, and sending a friendly error message or similar. If the files being sent are confidential or something like that, this is the suggested option.

```js
if (attachment.size > 8000000) {
  message.delete();
  message.channel.send("Sorry, but your file was too large!");
  return;
}
```

You can replace the statement after `message.delete` with anything you want. Note that this message also has a `return` with it, just to ensure that the bot doesn't try to upload the file (which it will definitely fail in).

Comment: Thank you really much! I can FINALLY end 4 hours of brainstorming!